# Quadtree decomposition

Tags: matlab, quadtree

I tried the quadtree decomposition using the following code, but every time I am getting an error.

```
>> I=imread('hyd.tif');

>> S=qtdecomp(I)
```

Or

```
>> I=imread('hyd.tif');

>> S=qtdecomp(I,.27)
```

Error:

```
??? Error using ==> qtdecomp>ParseInputs at 145

A must be two-dimensional

Error in ==> qtdecomp at 88

[A, func, params, minDim, maxDim] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is due to your image being in colour or RGB.  Try converting the image to grayscale before using the algorithm.

```
I = imread('hyd.tif');
Igray = rgb2gray(I);
S = qtdecomp(Igray);
```

Also make sure that your image dimensions are of a power of 2 or else the quadtree decomposition algorithm will not work.

Comment: can you help me with one more problem?